# MySQL - Copy row to another table with foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i want to copy 1 row from this table:

```
tableold
-----------
oid (primary key, auto_incremment)
name
age
detail
```

to this table:

```
tablenew
------------
nid (primary key, auto_incremment)
fid (foreign key to another table)
name
age
detail
```

With this SQL-Command:

```
INSERT INTO tablenew (tablenew.name, tablenew.age, tablenew.detail)
SELECT tableold.name, tableold.age, tableold.detail
FROM tableold
WHERE tableold.oid = 123;
```

But i get the error:

> ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'fid' doesn't have a default value

Is there any possibility to manually add the foreign key 'fid' to the SQL-Command?

*Edit, i have added the CREATE table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `othertable` (
  `fid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `value3` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `value4` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fid`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tablenew` (
  `nid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fid` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`),
  KEY `fid_fkey` (`fid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fid_fkey` FOREIGN KEY (`fid`) REFERENCES `othertable` (`fid`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tableold` (
  `oid` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`oid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and include the `CREATE` statements of the tables.

Comment: ;Is there any possibility to manually add the foreign key 'fid' to the SQL-Command?; - yes , same as any select you can include a constant.

Comment: I have added the CREATE statements.

Comment: Since you gave the creates, you don't need the original table descriptions. Also please don't add EDITs, just make your post the best presentation possible right now. PS We can expect this is a faq.. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. [ask] [help]

Comment: Read the manual about how the command works. Clearly explain what you are trying to do & what you expected & why you wrote what you wrote. PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Owners & followers of posts always get notified.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it:

```
INSERT INTO tablenew (tablenew.fid, tablenew.name, tablenew.age, tablenew.detail)
SELECT 'value', tableold.name, tableold.age, tableold.detail
FROM tableold
WHERE tableold.oid = value;
```